# Image is not Getting Generated Properly

Tags: java, file, io, hashmap, bufferedimage

Earlier today I asked a question on how to place images in sequence as part of a whole picture, so that I could generate 2D maps like you see in the old Pokemon games. Everything is tile-based.

I've come to the point where I generate the map itself, but it comes out a little funny.

I've tracked the problem to when I fill a HashMap with Tile Objects. A Tile Object holds a Name and a BufferedImage. What seems to be the problem is how the program reads the files from the folder filled with tiles (png files) and place them in the HashMap.

Here is the code for when I place the Tile Objects in the HashMap:

```
private static HashMap<Integer, Tile> getTiles(String path) throws IOException {
    HashMap<Integer, Tile> temp = new HashMap<>();
    File folder = new File(path);
    Tile tile;
    int counter = 0;
    for(File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if(file.isFile()) {
            try {
                if(file.getCanonicalPath().endsWith(".png")) {
                    tile = new Tile(file.getName(),ImageIO.read(file));
                    temp.put(counter, tile);
                    counter++;
                }
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Picture number " + counter + " could "
                        + "not be saved in the hashmap: \n"
                        + ioe.getMessage());
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And here is the Output when I do a toString() on the HashMap:

```
Tiles: (0,0.png)(1,1.png)(2,10.png)(3,100.png)....
```

Notice how after tile 1.png it starts counting 10, then 100, then 101, then 102...then when it reaches 112 it starts counting like this:

```
(112,2.png)(113,20.png)(114,200.png)(115,201.png)...
```

There is a total of 220 Tiles in this folder, (counting tile 0.png).
I clearly see what the problem is, but not how I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `folder.listFiles()` doesn't return the files in order. You could put these into a `List` and then sort it, but this isn't a great approach. If image `50.png` were removed and someone added `100000.png` then all the images after 49 would be shifted over by one. This could easily go undetected.

The better approach is to split the filename by the period and parse it to an int.

Here is how to split the filename:

```
String filename = file.getName();
String[] parts = filename.split("\\.");
counter = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
```

With this approach you no longer have to increment the counter. It also won't improperly number a tile if the image is missing.

Comment: Hmm, maybe sorting it in a list first sounds like an appealing idea...but I am worried that it will sort it the same way that listFiles() does if I use sort() on the list.

Comment: @Vipar You can control the sorting through the use if a `Comparator`

Comment: It is supposed to sort them lexicographically (i.e. the way it is now), but you can define your own comparator which will cast names to int and compare the values. Still, defining such a comparator is unsafe if you happen to have files with non-int names.

Comment: I would just parse the filename. I have included an example of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the names of your image files to 001.png, 002.png and so on (all names having the same length with leading zeros). This will let you read the files in the right order.

Comment: Is that really the only solution? :/